# Manifest merger failed while adding io.github.jeancsanchez.jcplayer:jcplayer:0.0.2

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying add jc player in my project. but when i try to sync gradle the give the following error. what should i do?
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@icon value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher_round) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-49
>       is also present at [io.github.jeancsanchez.jcplayer:jcplayer:0.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-43 value=(@mipmap/ic_launcher).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:icon"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-65:19 to override.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inc.musyc.musyc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'io.github.jeancsanchez.jcplayer:jcplayer:0.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Manifest for my project:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.inc.musyc.musyc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".Persistence"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".AppMainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inc.musyc.musyc_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".AppMainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LogInActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SocialMainActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".AppMainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ForgotpassActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".LogInActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".VerificationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AccountSettingActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChangeIntroActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChangePassActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ChangeDesActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity android:name=".DemoActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".dumbActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".CreatepostActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SinglePostViewActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: add this line in <application   tools:replace="android:icon">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add This in AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <application
    android:name=".Persistence"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
```

Comment: Wow! it worked. Thanks.  Can you explain what was the problem?

Comment: @NPN  io.github.jeancsanchez.jcplayer:jcplayer:0.0.2 this lib and your project both are added android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" this line in AndroidManifest.xml due to that you are getting this error

Comment: Just want to point out, that even though this solution works, you are better off to fix the library that was dumb enough to leave their application file with icons or name left in place. Libraries should never specify the icons or app name. You may want to fork and push that library to fix the real issue instead of putting an override hack in place