# Android merged manifest error

Tags: android

I am getting the following error.

> Merging Errors: Error: Attribute activity#
>   com.facebook.FacebookActivity@ theme value = (@android: style /
>   Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar) from AndroidManifest.xml: 50: 13 -
>   72 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml: 32: 13 - 63 value = (@style
>   / com_facebook_activity_theme).Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:theme"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml: 45:
>   9 - 52: 16 to override.app main manifest(this file), line 49

My AndroidManifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.android.blogtry"

    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        tools:replace="icon, label"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Disaster Management"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"
            tools:replace="android:value"/>

        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider21"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PostActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity android:name=".BlogSingleActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MyProfileActivity">
        </activity>

        <activity
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"

             />
        <activity
            android:name=".FbHomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.blogtry"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: just you have to clean project and than rebuild project in build tool.

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556571/manifest-merger-failed-while-adding-io-github-jeancsanchez-jcplayerjcplayer0-0/46556600#46556600

Comment: @jigarsavaliya I clean and rebuild the project. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @JRamesh  I followed the steps.  Still getting the same error.

Comment: @Ros remove tools:replace="android:theme" from FacebookActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use theme **style/com_facebook_activity_theme** from Facebook SDK:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" />
```

Or just remove theme line at all. Like:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

In this case theme will be pasted in manifest from Facebook SDK.

But in general **tools:replace="android:theme"** should work. At least in my projects it solves issues with facebook themes.

Comment: How we can change this? Isnt it from SDK that we cannot change?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Disaster Management"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:theme,icon,label">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tools:replace="android:theme` 
 and also remove  `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`
 from `facebookActivity` (from the `<activity>` tag)
 in your AndroidManifest.xml file since the latest Facebook SDK already includes it.